# React Native Router Flux nested routes in modal component

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have the next React Native Router Flux **Router** code:

```
<Scene key="home" component={Modal}>
      <Scene key="search">
        <Scene key="unfiltered" component={Unfiltered} />
        <Scene key="filtered" component={Filtered} />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key="menu">
         <Scene key="menu1" component={Menu1} />
         <Scene key="menu2" component={Menu2} />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key="calendar" component={Calendar} />
</Scene>
```

The problem is that when I call route **Actions.menu()** with two nested routes **menu1** and **menu2** from route **search.unfiltered**, nothing happens (for the first call I see action RNRF push and focus).

But if I call **Actions.calendar()** it's ok, as if I only call a **menu1** within **menu**.

I also tried this solution:

```
<Scene key="menu1" component="menu1">
   <Scene key="menu2" component="menu2" />
</Scene>
```

It works for **menu1**, but if I want to push to **menu2** nothing happens.

How properly create modal that contains nested routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to move menu into "Search" scene, because the RNRF supports only one nested scene if the parent scene is **Modal** component.